# How can I create a navigation controller that works with buttons instead of tableview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I just need to create a basic main menu with a navigation bar "main menu". Instead of using table view with the navigation controller I want to switch views by clicking on icons/buttons I create in the view space below the navigation bar, and for it to have the back button feature that automatically points back to the main menu view.

I looked over tutorials from blogs and videos, but they're all about using navigation controller with the table view. I'm using xcode 6, and xib files.

(also can someone post a link to a good, comprehensive introduction to gui programming for iphone?)

Thanks alot

Comment: I suggest you take a step back and go read some very basic tutorials on iOS. Xcode 6 is not a thing. Xcode 5 is the latest version. A navigation controller is a completely separate entity and can be used with any type of view controller and combination of views, not just table views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every UINavigationController has a rootViewController. That can be any viewcontroller not a UITableViewController necessarily.

A simple way is to create a new UIViewController and hook it up to UINavigationController

```
self.navigationcontroller.rootviewcontroller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"XibViewWithButtons" bundle:nil];
```

Drag and drop few buttons in your XIB to get the behavior.

If you are using StoryBoard then delete the default UITableViewController and attach [seague] between your new UIViewController and UINavigationController. Press cntr + drag your navigation controller to your new UIViewCntroller and select rootViewcontroller [1](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)

I would recommend going through hands on tutorial on [RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/)